# How to get a YAML flowchart in a pdf

Tags: pdf, yaml, minecraft

So i run a minecraft server using spigot. If you are familure with the game it is written in java and has a YML file. Anyways i remember something like this done way in the past where you could have a script run and it has a flowchat of permissions that inherit each other like it just has all of the permissions in a nice looking Flowchat. I have tried searching if something like this existed but i couldn't find anything and i am wondering if something like that is out there that i can use to make a easy to view PDF with all of the permissions. I am going to include a sample of the permission fike to show the format.

```
Moderator:
options:
  prefix: '&f[&aMod&f] '
  rank: '400'
inheritance:
- Member
permissions:
- essentials.clearinventory
- essentials.invsee
- essentials.kick
- essentials.mute
- essentials.tempban
- essentials.fly
- essentials.speed
- essentials.jump
- essentials.ban.notify
- essentials.mute.notify
- essentials.kick.notify
- essentials.enderchest
- essentials.top
- coreprotect.inspect
- nocheatplus.notify
- bm.notify.*
- nocheatplus.checks
- bm.command.tempban
- bm.command.warn
- bm.command.warn.offline
- bm.command.mute
- bm.command.bminfo.*
```

This is the format for all of the file. Where it says inheritance thats basily there are perms for a rank below that this rank inherits

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go on a minecraft-specific or a gaming page. Unless you're trying to write the tool yourself (you could convert it into a `dot` format and then to an image), this is not the right place to look for a ready-made tool.